# How should I organise vue.js components in a reasonable way?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Let's suppose I've got an index page index.vue made up of components like this:

**index.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
  <component-1 />
  <section class="section-1">
    <div class="container section-container">
      <component-2 />
      <component-3 /> 
    </div>
  </section>
  <component-4>
</div>
</template>

import Component-1 from '~/components/Component-1'
import Component-2 from '~/components/Component-2'
import Component-3 from '~/components/Component-3'
import Component-4 from '~/components/Component-4'


export default {
  components: {
      Component-1
      Component-2
      Component-3
      Component-4
  }
}

<style>
// style for the index page
</style>
```

Then I've also got a couple of files: `component-2.vue` and `component-3.vue` where I also declare some `css` style rules. Let's suppose that some of the divs of the above-mentioned components have unique classes and some of them don't. So, unless I'm very much mistaken, If I define how to style, say, `section-1` inside the `index.vue` file, the styles will be inherited by all its children. It means that it would be possible (not completely sure if reasonable though) to style elements with unique classes in the `component-1.vue` and `component-2.vue` files (using `<style scoped>`) and style elements with non-unique classes (in this case `section-1`, `container`, `section-container`) inside `index.vue`. And that's taking into account the fact that `section-1`, `container`, `section-container` are present in `component-1.vue` and `component-2.vue`.

So the question is: whether it's reasonable to structure code like this? That's what I'm trying to understand.
What I don't like about this structure is that css rules for some elements of component-2 and component-3 are defined outside these components.

Comment: Perhaps the code review site would be more apprproiate

Comment: @ShpielMeister Thanks, I will post it there as well.

Comment: Have you followed the official vuejs styleguide (https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/) ?

Comment: I would suggest which style's are used in more then one compo. can be declare in global css files (not even in index) total separate scss or less based file and which css are only available for compo you can declare it inside compo (scoped css). if needed you can override global css inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<style scoped>` to namespace the elements you want namespaced. I work on a pretty complex app written in Vue and when I need to style lots of elements that are shared by many components, I either include unscoped styles in the parent components, or I use scss or css modules in ./src/scss/ to style those shared elements. That way, you get to take advantage of Vue's scoped styles, but also create more reusable styles if you need.